# Emoji Problems LG G3 Cyanogenmod

Tags: cyanogenmod, lg-g3, emoticons

Last night I rooted and installed CyanogenMod 20150625 Nightly on my LG G3 D855. I also wanted to replace the emojis in the system to iOS emojis. I did that and it worked, except for one, the red heart.

It's not showing in the emoji part of my keyboard and when I see it in texts, it's a black, small heart.

The things I tried:

- Replacing the font file with two diffrent iOS emoji files.
- Trying to change the emojis with two Emoji Switching apps from Play Store.
- Deleting files that had emoji in the file name.

Every step I did gave me the same result. Any solution?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I faced with the same problem, and I found this GUIDE, I hope it will help you too!
http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/guide-fix-emoji-displaying-black-t3152314

You can also download the emoji packs from here: (the iOS pack worked me fine)
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2618523

Comment: Please summarize the guide here -- link only answers are discouraged since they become useless if the linked site goes down or moves/deletes the content.